# Can I control the error output of g++ compiler?

Tags: compiler-errors, g++

H3llo, everyone! I do have a question about controlling the output of my g++ compiler. I want only the error itself. I do not want to see all the include files and so on.
What I mean is, right now I have this message:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\include\wchar.h:54,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cwchar:44,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:38,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
             from source.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:413:3: warning: #warning "Direct definition of __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO is deprecated." [-Wcpp]
  413 | # warning "Direct definition of __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO is deprecated."
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\wchar.h:54,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cwchar:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from source.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:414:18: note: #pragma message: See <_mingw.h> for preferred feature activation methods.
  414 | # pragma message "See <_mingw.h> for preferred feature activation methods."
      |  

            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But the error line only comes after all these lines:

```
source.cpp:2:1: error: 'sing' does not name a type
    2 | sing namespace std;
      | ^~~~
```

Is there any way I can specify flags to my compiler so it will not show me all that directories but only error?

Thank you!

Comment: I am using MinGW-32 compiler and for some reason 
`-static -DONLINE_JUDGE -lm -s -x c++ -Wl,--stack=268435456 -O2 -std=c++11 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=0 -o Solution.exe ${$source} `
showed all the include files. So I just removed `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=0` and include files got rid off. Moreover, while using MinGW-64 with that flag, no include files were found. I think the problem could be the bit version of the compiler.